# Inputting a relationship array

Tags: c++, vector, input

I am trying to input an binary array which represents a relationship. As an example, the array:

```
001
000
100
```

would output (0,2),(2,0)

To do this I'm trying to grab characters one at a time from input, and then change counters based on encountering a newline.

Here is my code so far.

```
char inChar;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
while (inChar = ins.get() != '$') { 
        //$ is used to terminate input
        vector <int> orderedPair;
        if(inChar == '\n') {
            y++;
            x=0;
        } else {
            x++;
        }
        cout << inChar;
        int isPair = inChar - '0';
        if(isPair == 1){
            orderedPair.push_back(x);
            orderedPair.push_back(y);
            pointsList.push_back(orderedPair);
            orderedPair.clear();
        }

}
```

However, that cout line just outputs... smiley faces? No matter what I enter, I just get smiley faces. I'm lost here. I've looked for any accidentally assignment, and I thought it might be an issue with my typecasting but that is later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inChar = ins.get() != '$'` means `inChar = (ins.get() != '$')` and whether the character read is equal to `'$'` or not will be stored to `inChar` instead of the character itself. You can use `(inChar = ins.get()) != '$'` to save the input with checking if the input is `'$'`.

Also note that `orderedPair` will be cleared on each iteration because it is declared as local variable of the block, so you won't need `orderedPair.clear();`.